# Getting memory usage with php

Tags: java, php, linux, memory, ram

Hello I am using the following code to try to get the memory usage of java in PHP (on linux)

The part of the script that returns the PID works, but the code to get it's memory usage doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
$PID = exec('ps -eo pid,comm | grep \'java$\' | awk \'{print $1}\' | head -1');
$stats = explode("\n", shell_exec('pmap $(pgrep java) | grep \'total\\|\\:\''));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($stats); $i += 2) {
    if (strpos($stats[$i], "$PID") === 0) {
        preg_match('/\d+/', $stats[$i+1], $preRes);
        $res = $preRes[0];
    }
}

echo $res;
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? It returns 0 as the memory usage every time.

Comment: It's unnecessary to use double quotes around `$PID` here: `strpos($stats[$i], "$PID")`

Comment: how about simplifying your code so you can debug it? don't do `func(func(func(....)))` nesting. capture the output/return values of EVERY stage into separate individual code chunks, so you can see at what stage things are breaking. REmember: writing code is hard, debugging is even harder. If you write code that's at the limits of your ability to write, by definition you're unable to debug it.

Comment: Show us sample output from your shell commands.

Comment: Could you not just simplify it somewhat? For example, `ps auxw | grep \'java$\' | awk '{print $2,$5,$6}'` would output `PID Virtual-Memory Physical-Memory` per line

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the memory usage by simplifying me code to the following

```
$memory = exec('ps -eo rss,comm | grep \'java$\' | awk \'{print $1}\' | head -1');
$memory = $memory/1024;
echo $memory;
```